# How do I param the Controller Favorite Create method to have an index#view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I want to create a polymorphic model to favorite each objects I want to create to stock in my user page.
I am developing a web app to learn japanese and we can favorite different types of cards as kanas or kanjis and sentences.
So there are 3 objects and soon more to favorite.

I migrated a table which names Favorite :

```
  create_table "favorites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "favoritable_id"
    t.string   "favoritable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end
```

Here is the Favorite model `belongs_to`

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :favoritable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here are the Cards model `has_many`

```
class Symbole < ActiveRecord::Base

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :kanji_attribute, :allow_destroy => true
  has_many :sentence_symboles, :class_name => "SentenceSymbole", :foreign_key => "symbole_id"
  has_many :favorites, as: :favoritable     
end
```

and I added in sentence model too

```
class Sentence < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Authority::Abilities
    has_many :sentence_symboles, :class_name => "SentenceSymbole", :foreign_key => "sentence_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :favorites, as: :favoritable
end
```

Now here is the Favorite controller and I don't really know how to write the create method. Here is the Controller I do:

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @favorites = Favorite.where(user: current_user)
  end

  def create
    #Favorite.create(user_id: User.last.id, favoritable_id: Symbole.last.id, favoritable_type:"Symbole")
    @favorite = current_user.favoritable.favorites.create(symbole: @symbole, sentence: @sentence).first
    if @favorite.present?
       @favorite.destroy
    else
      @favorite = current_user.favorites.new(symbole: @symbole, sentence: @sentence)
      if not @symbole.favorites.where(user: current_user).take
          @sentence.favorites.where(user: current_user).take
          @favorite.save
      end
    end
    # redirect_to favs_path
    # redirect_to :back
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :ajax_update_favs }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @favorite = Favorite.find(params[:id])
    @favorite.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

Please could someone give me the right way to favorite all object I want and add in an favorite index#view.

Thank you for your help.

I think my question is simple but no. How to favorite each object I want with the def Create controller what is the best method?

I do that

```
def create
    #Favorite.create(user_id: User.last.id, favoritable_id: Symbole.last.id, favoritable_type:"Symbole")
    @favorite = @favoritable.favorites.build(favorite_params)
    @favorite.user = current_user
    @favorite.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :ajax_update_favorites }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why is the method calling destroy? Your question wasn't clear and trying to decipher has left me lost.  Typically, you'd use object.build and object save rather than create, but that is in no way a strict rule.  Also, usually, on success, create controller actions redirect to another location.   Leaving the view out of it for a second, what do you want to do?

Comment: @trh I don't create the view because I don't know what can I create my controller.

Comment: I still don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Sidenote: You can write your index method as `@favorites = current_user.favorites`

Comment: @trh My problem is I don't know if my controller is OK because I use for the first time the polymorphic model. And maybe you could have an expert eye on what I do in my controller because if my controller is ok I can create the routes and the view.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the problem entirely. It looks like you're overcomplicating `favoritesController#create`. If a record only should be favorited once, you should add a [uniqueness validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) in the `Favorite` model.

Assuming that you have your `user` model set up like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites

  # Rest..
end

def create
  @favorite = current_user.favorites.create(favorite_params)
  # This will create a new Favorite with user_id: current_user.id, favoritable_type: "Symbole", favoritable_id: 1337      
  # Is this the desired behaviour?

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :ajax_update_favs }
  end
end

private

def favorite_params
  params.require(:favorite).permit(:favoritable_type, :favoritable_id)
end
```

If this is called from javascript with jquery pass the type and id that you wan't to favorite.

```
  $.post( "/favorites", {
    favorites: { 
      favoritable_type: "Symbole",
      favoritable_id: 1337 
    } 
  });
```

Comment: I am a little bit upset if my question is not understandable but I use the polymorph. That's why it is not a uniqueness validation, isn't it?

Comment: You can still use the validation, even tho it's polymorphism. 

`validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: [:favoritable_type, :favoritable_id] }`

Which means that there can't be more than one combination of `user_id`, `favoritable_type` and `favoritable_id`